# Groupby with multiple columns and then create plot for top N

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset which I grouped by using 2 columns. Now I want to plot the graph for top N based on 1 column. To explain it better below are the example data set. This data set is created from main data set using groupby

| Data1 | Data2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 6 |
| A | y | 7 |
| A | z | 8 |
| B | y | 3 |
| B | z | 4 |
| B | u | 5 |
| C | x | 6 |
| C | y | 7 |
| C | v | 8 |
| D | v | 4 |
| D | y | 5 |
| D | z | 7 |
| E | t | 8 |
| E | u | 7 |
| E | x | 6 |
| F | s | 4 |
| F | s | 5 |
| F | r | 6 |

Now I want only top 3 data1 to create new data set and to plot the seaborn graph. Below is the desire result.

| Data1 | Data2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | x | 6 |
| A | y | 7 |
| A | z | 8 |
| B | y | 3 |
| B | z | 4 |
| B | u | 5 |
| C | x | 6 |
| C | y | 7 |
| C | v | 8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to keep the first N groups of Data1?

You can use [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) and slice it to get the first N groups in order, then use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3
out = df[df['Data1'].isin(df['Data1'].unique()[:N])]
```

Other option using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on the [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) (less efficient):

```
from itertools import islice
out = pd.concat([g for _,g in islice(df.groupby('Data1'), 3)])
```

output:

```
  Data1 Data2  Value
0     A     x      6
1     A     y      7
2     A     z      8
3     B     y      3
4     B     z      4
5     B     u      5
6     C     x      6
7     C     y      7
8     C     v      8
```